# Why is CurlF a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields, curl

I am having a really hard time understanding the concept of CurlF. Could someone help explain what it is and how we know that it's a vector field?

Comment: It depends what space you're in, it's not always a vector field depending on the dimension of the space.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, curl is by definition a vector field. Do you have an intuition about curl or something you thought was curl that either seems not to be a vector field or is less clear that it's a vector field? That would help you get an answer more like "Oh, that's not curl, that's [something else which isn't a vector field]" or "here's how you get a vector field out of that intuitive picture of curl" etc.

Comment: Answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550832/why-does-the-curl-vector-point-along-the-axis-of-rotation) may help.

Answer (score 1):

For 3 dimensional space the definition is $$ \text{curl}\overrightarrow{F}=\overrightarrow{\nabla}\times\overrightarrow{F}=\left(\frac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial z}\right)\hat{x}+\left(\frac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial x}\right)\hat{y}+\left(\frac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial y}\right)\hat{z} $$ And by definition it is a vector-field

Answer (score 0):

Some treatments of this subject distinguish between **polar vectors**, which are conventional vectors defining a quantity and a direction, and **axial vectors** (sometimes called **pseudovectors**) which describe a **rotational** quantity.

An axial vector is like this.

Imagine a wheel spinning round an axle. This can be described by an axial vector. *How fast* the wheel is spinning is identified by the *magnitude* of the vector. The direction of the axle is then identified with the *direction* of the vector. The direction is defined by the right hand rule: if you imagine your hand curled around the axle with your thumb sticking out, and your fingers pointing in the direction the wheel is spinning, the *positive direction* is the direction in which your *thumb* is pointing.

Now, you can loosely describe the **curl** of a field as an *axial vector* defining the spinning motion of a small element of the field. If this small element is turning, then there is an axial vector defining that turn. And the **curl** of a vector field is the **amount of turning at each point**.

The above is possibly inaccurate in order to give you a general feel for what is going on.